# Webpack: set default options used for a loader

Tags: webpack

I want to load load deps with a certain loader using require syntax

```js
const some = require('some-loader!./my-module')
```

This loader has options, but I would like to set them in config, not in inline in require statement

```js
require('some-loader?option=1&option=2!./my-module') // don't want to do this
```

I thought to use rule with empty `test/include`, but it seem not to work, it is trying to load everything with this rule. So I need to setup options, and then each time loader is used in require statement it would use those options.

The actual task is to use different options for different build configs. So the code (require) should stay the same, but options used for loading are different.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the code should stay the same why are you using those loaders inline?

In your `webpack.config.js` you can have:

```
const loadersConfig1 = require('./webpack.loaders.config1');
const loadersConfig2 = require('./webpack.loaders.config1');
const loadersConfig3 = require('./webpack.loaders.config1');

const generalConfig = require('./webpack.general.config');

module.exports = function () {
    let loadersConfig;

    switch(ENV.buildConfig) {
       case 1:
          loadersConfig = loadersConfig1; 
          break;
       case 2:
          loadersConfig = loadersConfig1; 
          break;
       case 3:
          loadersConfig = loadersConfig1;
          break;
    }
   
    return merge(general, loadersConfig)
}
```

Comment: Is not the answer to my question, loader is used inline because I can not point out in config which files should be loaded with this loader, it is convenient to determine this in code, not config.